# Why have we striven to accurately biosense things?

Tags: medical-device, glucose, sensors

As you may know, there are medical devices to track things to some certain points, like glucometers. Question is why do we strive to track such things (take glucose level for example) more accurately? (Curious: Talking specifically about this particular subject(glucometers), what's the reason to actually crave for precision?

these are a few sources I’ve been reading recently:

> https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/how-do-glucometers-work/

This article shows different approaches to measure the glucose level with different mechanisms with different level of accuracy and efficacy; using enzymatic detection, using photonics, and using carbon nanotubes.

Also this book

> https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780857096609/nanosensors-for-chemical-and-biological-applications

in chapter 2,

> [Electrochemical nanosensors for blood glucose analysis]

discusses the detection of glucose using various approaches like again enzymatic detection, Nanosensors, Nano-sized materials like carbon nanotubes, gold nanowire array electrode for non-enzymatic voltammetric and amperometric glucose detection and...

And also the last one : Nanophotonics Paras N. Prasad Page 268-269 glucose detection using photonic crystal sensors

> https://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/406/Nanophotonics_0471649880.pdf

(I asked this question just out of curiosity)

"why bother improving the accuracy of glucometers?" I'm saying that, with the typical glucometer devices, we are able to measure the glucose level in the bloodstream and with some more advanced methods(or maybe alternative ways), we are trying to make the measurement more accurate. Question is why, while we are already able to measure it. I mean is there a medical condition that there is a need to measure with higher accuracy than the typical glucometers?

Pt: I don't come from a medical background,so my question may sound a little bit obscure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking why measuring devices are made to be as accurate as practical?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't ask my question any better. I was referring to the fact that we actually are already ABLE to measure the glucose level in the blood to some extent, but why do we want to measure it even more accurately? I mean, the same methodology applies to the other devices as well, they have some specific usage and are already doing SOMETHING and reasonably practical compared to what we want.My question is why should we try perfecting them while we are able to get what we want (for example measuring glucose level in the blood) This is a BME student asking this question.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're asking. Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require questions here to demonstrate some degree of prior research. For example, can you cite the sources that lead you to believe there's an effort underway to measure glucose more accurately? (And apparently other medical measurements as well?) Can you also explain your reasoning that what we have is "good enough?"

Comment: Yeah looks like I need to have a look there. Btw Yeah, these are a few sources I’ve been reading recently:
https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/how-do-glucometers-work/
This article shows different approaches to measure the glucose level with different mechanisms with different level of accuracy and efficacy; using enzymatic detection, using photonics, and using carbon nanotubes.

Comment: Also this book[ https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780857096609/nanosensors-for-chemical-and-biological-applications ] contains a full chapter [Electrochemical nanosensors for blood glucose analysis] discussing the detection of glucose using various approaches like again enzymatic detection, Nanosensors, Nano-sized materials like carbon nanotubes, gold nanowire array electrode for non-enzymatic voltammetric and amperometric glucose detection and ….

Comment: And also the last one : Nanophotonics Paras N. Prasad
Page 268-269
glucose detection using photonic crystal sensors
https://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/406/Nanophotonics_0471649880.pdf
(I asked this question just out of curiosity)

Comment: From good (which has no appropriate meaning in academia) I meant to say sufficient; sufficient to measure something (that's why I'm here, insecure about the term sufficient, like is glucometer itself sufficient to measure the glucose level in the bloodstream? and if no, then why? and some related questions. )

Comment: Whether or not glucometers are sufficient isn't what your question asks. In fact, it appears to ask rather the opposite; ie, why bother improving the accuracy of glucometers? And the sources you've provided need to be in the question itself, not in comments. So you have some editing to do. But a quick glance at your links shows the links are technical articles written by engineers involved in the glucometer business. So it seems pretty logical that they're trying to improve their products, which once again leaves me not understanding what you're asking. Are you asking why advance science?

Comment: "why bother improving the accuracy of glucometers?" Exactly! That's why I asked it here (Medical sciences) I'm saying that, with the typical glucometer devices, we are able to measure the glucose level in the bloodstream and with some more advanced methods(or maybe alternative ways), we are trying to make the measurement more accurate. Question is why, while we are already able to measure it. I mean is there a medical condition that there is a need to measure with higher accuracy than the typical glucometers? that's all! My apologies it turned out to be a long discussion.